# Quartzite counter installation progress Feedback

Tags: repair, installation, quartz

Just last year I had concrete counter tops that turned out bad. So not we are fully redoing the project and I got a contractor. The contractor said he does countertop I stalls all the time. He also said on occasion he does the Fabricating.

So he picked up my slab and went to work on it. The only information he asked me for was which pieces did I want where? And how do I want my edges? Informed him where and told him I wanted the square edges.

Just a little ways through I noticed some imperfections that I am very concerned with.
1. There are seams in the lip. He did not do a 45 degree angle cut.

2. There was a portion not cut long enough which he had to ad another piece. It doesn't look professional.
3. There are burned blemishes from the sanding buffing or polishing process.
4. One of the edges is very very rough. It is not smooth like the top of the counter.

He is not done yet, but I think three are some issues and major flaws. I'm not sure if all my pictures will load. But please based on what you see, what do you recommend.

What should I do? How would you handle it?

Please provide sound feedback and view the progress pictures.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not a quality job. I would tell him to stop and address the problems with the counter.

Comment: I can't get another person to work I it because they would want to sell me through there guys.